# Deciding on application architecture

Tags: .net, architecture

I'm redeveloping a simple application that exists now as a public facing website using SQL Server in our DMZ, another Access front-end & backend for our desktop users.  I also have to locally install the access version for field crews without network access(or internet access).

I'm trying to develop an application(s) from scratch that can accomplish all 3 usage scenarios:

1. Desktop user connected to our network
2. Laptop user with NO network connectivity or internet
3. Public webpage user

A little about the application.  It consists of 100,000+ tiff images on a file system.  The database stores metadata about the image as well as a relative URL to the image.  There is the image table, user table(to track who uses it and permissions), and history table (to track who edited what on image table).  The system is only edited by about 3 people who will be network connected, it's primarily a lookup system.

I've started with winforms and EF 4 and realized it's pretty much overkill for my needs.  So the questions are:
Is there a way to support caching the db and files locally during runtime to "take an app offline" then sync up when back at the office? (If there is, I would prefer that if they never select that option it doesn't put an empty SQL db on their PC when installed, as I can install the db beforehand on each laptop since they are only ones that will need it)

Should I just use ADO.net as the database and querying is pretty straight forward?  Do I gain anything from EF?  There is almost no relationships, differing business logic etc.  The only complex query is the search that looks up the metadata for the file using AND/OR's lists of field values etc.

Comment: Are you asking whether EF is overkill (in why case: why do you think that?), or are you asking how to synchronise an application with a server?  The two questions are very different (and the latter is much more complex!).

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering what I gain from EF?  I'm pretty new at writing windows applications, but it looks like there are A LOT of features that it provides that don't necessarily help in such simple applications.  The synchronization is probably suited to a different separate question, but I'm wondering what technologies/api/frameworks exist that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think for your scenario as a DB matching good NoSQL databases. Look at CouchDB and use it like storage with Synchronization (Replication).

Cite about CouchDB:

> CouchDB supports multiple DB replicas running in difference machines
>   and provide a mechanism to synchronize their data. This is useful in
>   occasionally connected applications (e.g. PDA). In this case, user can
>   work in a disconnected mode for a time period and store his data
>   changes locally. Later on when he connects back to his corporate
>   network, he can synchronize his changes back to his corporate DB.

You can read about in book "CouchDB: The Definitive Guide" [here](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/index.html) or on [CouchDb site](http://www.couchbase.com/).

CouchDb has REST API, therefore you can use any REST client (even WebClient/HttpWeRequest) or, for example, [RestSharp library](http://restsharp.org/).

Or look at side of [Mongo NoSQL](http://www.mongodb.org/) database. It has a cool feature called GridFS (distributed file storage), that can help to work with a lot of binary data. And than gain almost the same  but using  Mongo replication features.

Comment: @home Cite "Should I just use ADO.net as the database and querying is pretty straight forward? Do I gain anything from EF?". As I understand Author thinks to stay with EF/ADO.NET or not to stay. My answer is no and I've suggested alternative scenario related to databases sync that Author want to implement. So why you think "no" answer with alternative suggestion and explanation is not an answer.